# zApDtG guest account?

Tags: accounts

I'm using ubuntu 13.10

Where did guest account zApDtG with root privileges come from? I can't gather much information, as this guest account has root privileges and being a brand new user, I don't. Is there a default root account created in the guest account file for all new users?

I know it has root privileges because when I try to move, delete, or any other file manipulation, it tells me that it has root privileges and I don't have the proper permissions to change anything.

Comment: What does `ls -l /home/zApDtG` say? Anything suspicious in the logs? Sounds like you got hacked.

Comment: Running this command should remove the user: `sudo userdel zApDtG` If the account had a folder under `home`, type `sudo rm -rf /home/zApDtG` to remove it.

Comment: Are you sure it has root privileges? You don't have the right to modify files in another user's account by default, that does not mean that they have root rights.

Comment: Does the problem persist? I had the same problem some time ago. But it disappeared after restart.